# What does a utxo output or vout of 0 mean?

Tags: utxo, output

If I sent myself bitcoin to a new address on a different hardware wallet and it was all of my funds with no change, is it normal for the utxo output or "vout" to be 0?

It is my understanding that if I was not sending all my bitcoin and receiving some back in my change address that output or vout would now be 1?

Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 3):

`vout` is simply the index of the output in the outputs list of a transaction. It is used to identify which output of a transaction is being spent. It is a 0-based index, so the first output is index 0, the second is index 1, and so on. There is no special significance assigned to outputs of any index, and in fact, many wallets will randomize the order of outputs for some additional privacy.

If your transaction only has one output, then the only possible `vout` is 0.

Comment: Ava thanks for this response. Just to make sure I'm understanding you correctly. If I emptied my wallet of all my bitcoin and sent it to a new address with no change because I emptied it, then the output would have to be 0 Because I only had one output (the new address)?

Comment: Yes. The `vout` always counts up starting at 0.